# Flutter build apk keeps failing `checkDebugDuplicateClasses`

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I tried various solution from StackOverflow and github issues but still I can't build an apk from my Apple M2.

- I added kotlin version to gradle.build
- Edited distributionUrl to gradle 8.1.1 (latest)

I don't understand what is the issue…

flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.1, on macOS 14.1.1 23B81 darwin-arm64, locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 3.19.1 on channel stable at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.16.0/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision abb292a07e (6 days ago), 2024-02-20 14:35:05 -0800
    • Engine revision 04817c99c9
    • Dart version 3.3.0
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/winston/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15C500b
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.82.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)            
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.1.1 23B81 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 122.0.6261.69

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

here are some log from the flutter build apk --debug:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              3.5s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `android/settings.gradle`

```
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false
```